# Utilize iOS TabBar as TaskBar

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm making an application that requires the use of a dock (think Mac dock) where I can have different items that I can drag out onto a map view.

It would make sense to me to just use and subclass a UITabBar, since you can easily add items to that bar in the interface builder. However, I'm not sure how I would transform a UITabBar into something more dynamic like the Mac dock, where things are only highlighted when the user touches them, copies of that tab can be dragged out, ect.

To that end, just a side question, what's the difference between the UITabBarDelegate and UITabBarControllerDelegate protocols?

I also thought of another way I could implement my task bar/dock using some sort of collection view with UIImageViews. That would be easier in terms of implementing drag and drop, highlight selection, ect but I would lose that nice, native iOS feel that the UITabBar has.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do one thing. create a custom class for tabbar add a view over it. and add image views over the view place small images in that view and add gesture recognizer over it. When the finger comes over it replace the smaller image with the larger one. and also change the tab bar selection if the user taps over it. you can do this by using tabbar property. or you call the tabbar delegate manually when the tap is made.